# handled dynamically missing source columns in ssis

Tags: ssis, ssis-2012

I have a small SSIS question. I'm extracting data from a MySQL table with a varying column list to a SQL Server table with a fixed column list.

source table:  Test(mysql server)

```
 id  |     name   |    sal      | deptno | loc     |   referby
 1   |      abc   |     100     |10      | hyd     |    xyz
 2   |      mnc   |     200     |20      |chen     |    pqr
```

First I select MySQL table configuration, then I drag and drop oledbdestination for MySQL server table configuration. I configure the target table, and after that the package works fine and the data looks like below.

Target table :  Test (sql server )

```
id   |     name   |     sal     |deptno        | loc           |referby
 1   |      abc   |     100     |10            | hyd           |    xyz
 2   |      mnc   |     200     |20            |chen           |    pqr
```

The second time I run the package, a column has been removed from the source table's schema, so the package fails. I open the MySql server testsource configuration and I edit the query to return NULL for the missing column:

```
 select id,'null' as name,sal,deptno,loc,referby from test
```

I rerun the package and the data looks like this.

Target table :  Test (sql server )

```
id   |     name   |     sal     |deptno        | loc           |referby
 1   |      null  |     100     |10            | hyd           |    xyz
 2   |      null  |     200     |20            |chen           |    pqr
```

I always truncate the target table and load data.

The target table has an unchanging list of columns while the source table's column list can vary. **I do not want keep editing the query to account for possible missing columns.** How I can handle this at the package level?

Answer (score 2):

A couple ideas:

- **Use dynamic SQL.** Replace your straightforward `SELECT ...` with a query that iterates through the target table's column list (perhaps fetched via [`SHOW COLUMNS`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/show-columns.html)), builds a `SELECT` query that inserts NULL for the missing columns then execute it via [`PREPARE` and `EXECUTE`](http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2014/06/20/mysql-dynamic-sql-with-execute-and-prepare-statements/).

  The query-generating query would need to produce a `SELECT` statement containing the fixed set of columns your target table expects to see. If an expected column doesn't exist in the source, the query-generating query should insert the placeholder `NULL AS ColumnName` in the query.

  (I'm not a MySQL expert so I'm unsure of MySQL's exact capabilities in this regard but in theory this approach sounds workable.)
- **Use a Script Component as the data source.** Configure this component with the output columns you expect. Have the component query the source database (maybe using a simple `SELECT * FROM ....`) and then copy *only the **relevant** columns that exist* from source to output row buffer. With this approach, columns that don't exist will automatically be outputted into the data flow as null/their default value because the Script Component won't have set them to a value.

Comment: HI  to solve this issue  if you donot mine can you provide dynamic sql query  or script code for two columns how we do please give the solution.

Comment: @user1623352, why don't you post each as a separate question? One question would be tagged SQL/MySQL, asking how to build a query that always returns a fixed set of columns even if the source table's schema changed (you wouldn't necessarily even need to mention SSIS in this question). The other would be aimed back here at the SSIS tag asking how to build a Script component that does what you want. With each question, it would be best if you posted some code showing what you've tried to do or explained how you tried to find the answer on your own and were stumped.

Answer (score 0):

SSIS is very rigid when it comes to dynamic sources like this. I think your best bet would be to explore BIML which could generate a new package for you each time you need to "refresh" the schema.

http://www.sqlservercentral.com/stairway/100550/